# Good day everyone, I have an XML file in a CLOB field of an ORACLE table. I'd like to extract the content of the XML to fill an oracle table

Tags: xml, oracle, extract, clob

Hi and thanks a lot in advance for your help,

First, please note that I'm a newbies with XML processing, first time your text for me.

So, I have an XML file stored in an oracle table in a CLOB field.
The XML content has the below structure and contains multiple occurrence of some values.
I need to extract the content of the XML to insert values into an oracle table.
I'm already able to read different part of the XML but not in a structured way for the moment.
Could someone help me defining a query that will allow me to extract the full content of the XML.
Once this extract done I will be able to continue the process of loading the data into my tables.

the query I use give me this

```
SELECT xt.recurring_data, xt2.reference_number
FROM TEST_LUXAIR_TEMP_LOAD_PROD.CUSTOM_XML_CLIENT_DATA a,
     XMLTable('/CCTS063A/RequestDetails/requestedAdditionalInformation/additionalCode'
              PASSING XMLType(a.xml_content)
              COLUMNS recurring_data VARCHAR2(100) PATH '.',
              reference_number VARCHAR2(100) PATH '/CCTS063A/RequestDetails/requestedAdditionalInformation/requestedDocuments/referenceNumber') xt,
     TEST_LUXAIR_TEMP_LOAD_PROD.CUSTOM_XML_CLIENT_DATA b,
     XMLTable('/CCTS063A/RequestDetails/requestedAdditionalInformation/requestedDocuments/referenceNumber'
              PASSING XMLType(a.xml_content)
              COLUMNS reference_number VARCHAR2(100) PATH '.') xt2;
```

---

```
A10 helloworld_max70_chars_1
A10 helloworld_max70_chars_2
A10 helloworld_max70_chars_3
A10 helloworld_max70_chars_4
A10 helloworld_max70_chars_5
A20 helloworld_max70_chars_1
A20 helloworld_max70_chars_2
A20 helloworld_max70_chars_3
A20 helloworld_max70_chars_4
A20 helloworld_max70_chars_5
A30 helloworld_max70_chars_1
A30 helloworld_max70_chars_2
A30 helloworld_max70_chars_3
A30 helloworld_max70_chars_4
A30 helloworld_max70_chars_5
A40 helloworld_max70_chars_1
A40 helloworld_max70_chars_2
A40 helloworld_max70_chars_3
A40 helloworld_max70_chars_4
A40 helloworld_max70_chars_5
```

while I'm waiting foe this

```
A10 
A20 helloworld_max70_chars_1
A20 helloworld_max70_chars_2
A30 helloworld_max70_chars_3
A30 helloworld_max70_chars_4
A30 helloworld_max70_chars_5
A40
```

Ideally my full extract should look like

```
TS.LU    3     A10    
TS.LU    3     A20    helloworld_max70_chars_1
TS.LU    3     A20    helloworld_max70_chars_2
TS.LU    3     A30    helloworld_max70_chars_3
TS.LU    3     A30    helloworld_max70_chars_4
TS.LU    3     A30    helloworld_max70_chars_5
TS.LU    3     A40
```

my XML file look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CCTS063A>
    <messageSender>TS.LU</messageSender>
    <RequestDetails>
        <requestID>3</requestID>       
        <requestedAdditionalInformation>
            <additionalCode>A10</additionalCode>
        </requestedAdditionalInformation>
        <requestedAdditionalInformation>
            <additionalCode>A20</additionalCode>
            <requestedDocuments>
                <referenceNumber>helloworld_max70_chars_1</referenceNumber>
            </requestedDocuments>
            <requestedDocuments>
                <referenceNumber>helloworld_max70_chars_2</referenceNumber>
            </requestedDocuments>
        </requestedAdditionalInformation>
        <requestedAdditionalInformation>
            <additionalCode>A30</additionalCode>
            <requestedDocuments>
                <referenceNumber>helloworld_max70_chars_3</referenceNumber>
            </requestedDocuments>
            <requestedDocuments>
                <referenceNumber>helloworld_max70_chars_4</referenceNumber>
            </requestedDocuments>
            <requestedDocuments>
                <referenceNumber>helloworld_max70_chars_5</referenceNumber>
            </requestedDocuments>           
        </requestedAdditionalInformation>
        <requestedAdditionalInformation>
            <additionalCode>A40</additionalCode>
        </requestedAdditionalInformation>
    </RequestDetails>
</CCTS063A>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep nested attributes in sync with their parents. This may be achieved by usage of `XMLType` result column of `XMLTable` function and another `XMLTable` unnesting for `requestedDocuments` collection.

Result query is:

```
select
  t.id,
  xmlt1.messageSender,
  xmlt1.requestid,
  xmlt1.additionalCode,
  xmtl2.referenceNumber
from t
  cross apply xmltable(
    '/CCTS063A/RequestDetails/requestedAdditionalInformation'
    passing xmltype(xmldoc)
    columns
      additionalCode varchar2(10) path 'additionalCode',
      requestid varchar2(10) path './../requestID',
      messageSender varchar2(10) path './../../messageSender',
      docs xmltype path 'requestedDocuments'
  ) xmlt1
  outer apply xmltable(
    '/*'
    passing xmlt1.docs
    columns
      referenceNumber varchar2(100) path 'referenceNumber'
  ) xmtl2
```

which for your sample data results in:

| ID | MESSAGESENDER | REQUESTID | ADDITIONALCODE | REFERENCENUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TS.LU | 3 | A10 | *null* |
| 1 | TS.LU | 3 | A20 | helloworld_max70_chars_1 |
| 1 | TS.LU | 3 | A20 | helloworld_max70_chars_2 |
| 1 | TS.LU | 3 | A30 | helloworld_max70_chars_3 |
| 1 | TS.LU | 3 | A30 | helloworld_max70_chars_4 |
| 1 | TS.LU | 3 | A30 | helloworld_max70_chars_5 |
| 1 | TS.LU | 3 | A40 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_eRzCtQa)

Note that `OUTER APPLY` is required for the second `XMLTable` to handle items with no `requestedDocuments` children.

Comment: Hi, Wonderful, this is exactly what I'm looking for. So if I correctly understand, each time you have a sublevel of data (for example a list of children under the reference number) you have to add a new table to parse like you did with xmtl2.

Comment: @Locupus Yes, it should be like this for every lelev with possible missing elements. The path you specify in the XMLTable is used to generate node sequence to treat them as rows, so there will be no row for parents with no children under specified path. Like for `additionalCode = 10` in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You have three levels of XMLTable XQuery evaluations you need to process, and use do a LEFT OUTER JOIN between them.

Create a new table to store XML documents

```
CREATE TABLE myxmltable (
  id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (CACHE 5) PRIMARY KEY,
  sxmldoc  SYS.XMLTYPE
);
```

Insert your document in the new table

```
DECLARE
  v_xml   SYS.XMLTYPE;
  v_doc   CLOB;
BEGIN
  -- XMLTYPE created from a CLOB
  v_doc := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CCTS063A>
    <messageSender>TS.LU</messageSender>
    <RequestDetails>
        <requestID>3</requestID>       
        <requestedAdditionalInformation>
            <additionalCode>A10</additionalCode>
        </requestedAdditionalInformation>
        <requestedAdditionalInformation>
            <additionalCode>A20</additionalCode>
            <requestedDocuments>
                <referenceNumber>helloworld_max70_chars_1</referenceNumber>
            </requestedDocuments>
            <requestedDocuments>
                <referenceNumber>helloworld_max70_chars_2</referenceNumber>
            </requestedDocuments>
        </requestedAdditionalInformation>
        <requestedAdditionalInformation>
            <additionalCode>A30</additionalCode>
            <requestedDocuments>
                <referenceNumber>helloworld_max70_chars_3</referenceNumber>
            </requestedDocuments>
            <requestedDocuments>
                <referenceNumber>helloworld_max70_chars_4</referenceNumber>
            </requestedDocuments>
            <requestedDocuments>
                <referenceNumber>helloworld_max70_chars_5</referenceNumber>
            </requestedDocuments>           
        </requestedAdditionalInformation>
        <requestedAdditionalInformation>
            <additionalCode>A40</additionalCode>
        </requestedAdditionalInformation>
    </RequestDetails>
</CCTS063A>';
  v_xml := SYS.XMLTYPE.createXML(v_doc);
  INSERT INTO myxmltable (SXMLDOC) VALUES (v_xml);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Run the query

```
select ccts.messageSender, ccts.requestID, rd.additionalCode, rn.referenceNumber
  from myxmltable mxt
     LEFT OUTER JOIN xmltable('/CCTS063A' passing mxt.sxmldoc
       columns 
             messageSender  VARCHAR2(10)  PATH 'messageSender'
           , requestID      NUMBER        PATH 'RequestDetails/requestID'
           , RequestDetails XMLTYPE       PATH 'RequestDetails') ccts
     ON 1=1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN xmltable('/RequestDetails/requestedAdditionalInformation' passing ccts.RequestDetails
       columns
             additionalCode     VARCHAR2(4) PATH 'additionalCode'
           , requestedDocuments XMLTYPE     PATH 'requestedDocuments') rd
     ON 1=1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN xmltable('/requestedDocuments' passing rd.requestedDocuments
       columns
             referenceNumber VARCHAR2(70) PATH 'referenceNumber') rn
     ON 1=1
  where mxt.ID = 1;
```

Results

```
"MESSAGESENDER" "REQUESTID" "ADDITIONALCODE"    "REFERENCENUMBER"
"TS.LU" 3   "A10"   ""
"TS.LU" 3   "A20"   "helloworld_max70_chars_1"
"TS.LU" 3   "A20"   "helloworld_max70_chars_2"
"TS.LU" 3   "A30"   "helloworld_max70_chars_3"
"TS.LU" 3   "A30"   "helloworld_max70_chars_4"
"TS.LU" 3   "A30"   "helloworld_max70_chars_5"
"TS.LU" 3   "A40"   ""
```